# apply function with a conditional statement using two dataframe

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dataframe

I have two data frame x and y.

```
x<-data.frame("j"=c("A","B","C"),"k"=c(1,90,14))
  x j  k
  1 A  1
  2 B 90
  3 C 14

y<-data.frame("A"=c(1,0,0,1,1),"B"=c(0,1,0,0,1),"C"=c(1,1,1,0,0))
  A B C
1 1 0 1
2 0 1 1
3 0 0 1
4 1 0 0
5 1 1 0
```

I need a function with a conditional statement where if in the data set y there is a 0 a replace by -1 or 1 replace by 1 in the column A and so on to get this result.

```
z<-data.frame("A"=c(1,-1,-1,1,1),"B"=c(-90,90,-90,-90,90),"C"=c(14,14,14,-14,-14))
   A   B   C
1  1 -90  14
2 -1  90  14
3 -1 -90  14
4  1 -90 -14
5  1  90 -14
```

Comment: If you replace the 0s with -1s, it's basically multiplication: `(-(y == 0) + y) * matrix(x$k, nrow(y), ncol(y), byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: if the order pf columns and rows are matched between x and y: `y[y==0] <- -1 ; 
y* x$k[col(y)]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fun one-liner in base R that uses a number of good-to-know functions.

```
setNames(do.call(data.frame, Map(function(x, y) x * c(-1, 1)[y+1], x$k, y)), LETTERS[1:3])
   A   B   C
1  1 -90  14
2 -1  90  14
3 -1 -90  14
4  1 -90 -14
5  1  90 -14
```

The inner most function `x * c(-1, 1)[y+1]` takes the value of x (which is a scalar -- either 1, 90, or 14) and multiplies it by either negative -1 or 1 depending on the value of y.

`Map` takes the values of x$k for x and the variables of the data.frame y for the y argument, performs the function on each pair and returns a list. with three vectors.

This list is converted to a data.frame with `do.call` and the names of the variables are supplied with `setNames`.

Comment: Is there a way to get these results using apply or lapply and ifelse?

Comment: It might be interesting to note that `Map` is a wrapper for `mapply`. `ifelse` tends to be pretty slow, the `c(-1, 1)[y+1]` is actually performing the role of `ifelse`, but is faster. The `ifelse` version would be `ifelse(y==1, y, -1)`.